# Regular expression to check whether one or more special characters are present in string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am using the below code:

```
email = "yash@"
string_check= re.compile('[@.]')

if(string_check.search(email) == None):
    print('invalid')
else:
    print('valid')
```

This rightly evaluates to 'valid'. However, if I want to ensure that the **string strictly contains both '@' and '.'** then what is the way in which I can achieve it?

I have also tried below code but it does not work with special charcaters:

```
import re
arr = ['@', '.']
# str = "hello people"

str = "yash"
if any(re.findall('|'.join(arr), str)):
    print('Found a match')
else:
    print('No match found')
```

This evaluates to "Found a match" despite having neither "@" nor "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all()` function, no need to use regex:

```
arr = ['@', '.']
email = "yash@"

if all(ch in email for ch in arr):
    print('valid')
else:
    print('not valid')
```

Prints:

```
not valid
```

Comment: This worked. I was just thinking of a way if possible without looping. Also, is there a way I can check if only one occurrence of '@' is present. If there are more than one '@" then print invalid?

Comment: @YashSaraiya You can do `email.count('@')`. If it's greater than 1 then print invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Andrej Kesely does work, but the complexity could be much much better. His solution has a complexity of O(mn), where m is the length of `arr` and n is the length of `email`. Here is an alternative solution (might look worse, but it has a better complexity):

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(email)
if all(counter[ch] > 0 for ch in arr):
    print('valid')
else:
    print('non valid')
```

Here the complexity is O(max(m, n))